# PiFm On AllWinner SoC

Tags: arm, orange-pi

I want to make PiFm https://github.com/rm-hull/pifm/blob/master/pifm.cpp compatible on OrangePi One ( h3 AllWinner ARM processor )

I guess, to do compatible i just? set the good register addresses no ?

On PiFm i found those address :

```
#define CM_GP0CTL (0x7e101070)
#define GPFSEL0 (0x7E200000)
#define CM_GP0DIV (0x7e101074)
#define CLKBASE (0x7E101000)
#define DMABASE (0x7E007000)
#define PWMBASE  (0x7e20C000) /* PWM controller */
```

But on the H3 datasheet http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/H3/Allwinner_H3_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf i can't translate these addresses.

I'm not a expert on ARM/Programmation but PiFm will work on OrangePi One ?

(Sorry for my english, i'm french)

Thanks by advance 
Regards

Comment: Please remove C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Converting this program to run on the Allwinner SoC would involve rewriting it entirely, if it's even possible.

PiFm depends on being able to turn the Broadcom SoC's PWM peripheral on and off through crafted DMA requests. This is not an option on the Allwinner; the PWM peripheral does not have a DMA port (datasheet page 193).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I see on the AllWinner datasheet the processor has PLL  ( Phase-locked loop ) this can up to several mhz this can be used for drive GPIO ? 
I can't find any documented example to do that.

Comment: @kiki67100 No. The PLLs are used to generate clock signals used internally by the processor.